# How to integrate $(e^x-1)/x$

Tags: integration, special-functions

How to integrate $\frac{(e^x-1)}{x}$ and find constant $c$ when $F(0)=0$.
I have already tried wolframalpha, but this didn't help to solve this.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+(e%5Ex-1)%2Fx) gives a perfectly reasonable answer. See that the integral cannot be expressed by means of elementary functions.

Answer (score 0):

Go for infinite series.

$$e^x -1=x+ x^2/2+x^3/6+....$$

$$\frac {e^x-1}{x}=1+x/2+x^2/6+...$$

Integrate and you get $$ \int 1+x/2+x^2/6+....=x+x^2/4+x^3/{18}+....$$

Answer (score 0):

It actually has no closed form integral, but can be expressed using Taylor series as following:$${e^x-1\over x}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{x^{n-1}\over n!}$$Therefore$$\int {e^x-1\over x}dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{x^{n}\over n\times n!}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Except for the sign of the argument, this integral is the [Ein function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Definition_by_Ein), which (as others have said) is not elementary.